# Azure redis cache multiple databases

Tags: caching, redis, azure-redis-cache

Whenever I am inserting a key in any one db of the redis cache, it gets inserted in all 16 dbs and removing the key from any one db deletes the same from all DBs. Attached is the screen shot showing the same. As per my knowledge, the DBs are independent of each other and at a time any key should be inserted/removed from the current DB in use. Could anyone please explain the observed behaviour?[image]

Comment: What is the console you're using? It could be due to new connections being made after each command, so you'll always end up issuing commands to the default db.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Redis Portal Console currently doesn't handle the Select statement correctly (because each command goes out on a new connection), so you are actually doing a get on DB 0.  This is a known issue and we are in the process of creating the V2 of the portal console, which will fix this issue.  Rough ETA is sometime in the next couple of months.

Comment: hey JonCole. Any updates about "Azure redis cache multiple databases

"? It is middle of March already :-). Thanks

Comment: We have pushed some of the changes out to the portal and you should see improvements already.  We have another set of changes that are partially rolled out as well, including better support for clustered caches etc. We expect these additional changes to be available to all customers within the next week or two.  You will know when you have received the latest updates when you run the "INFO Server" command in the console and see that your version of Redis is 3.2.7 or newer